# openssl self signed sertificate, need 3 files, got only 2

Tags: ssl, postfix, ssl-certificate, openssl

Hello I try to config my mail server, I do :

```
sudo openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -sha512 -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/private/server.pem
```

but in postfix config, is needed 3 files : (exemple)

```
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/newreq.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/newcert.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile =  /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

So how I got the CAfile ?

Comment: Note that if you can get a Lets Encrypt cert, you can use that for TLS on postfix.  Point the `smtpd_tls_key_file` at `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem` and `smtpd_tls_cert_file` at `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem`  - same with `dovecot` .... may save you other self-signed certificate related headaches...

Comment: do you have a complete tutoriel for use this? it's secure? how are you sure? thx.

Comment: Matrix - yes.  Ask over on unix.stackexchage.com since it is more appropriate there than here

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a self signed certificate the CA is the certificate, so your configuration should be something like:

```
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile =  /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem
```

using the same file for cert and for CA.